# Is it possible to define a bdc model in code

Tags: development, bdc-model

is it possible to define an external contentType in code?
As an alternative: Is it possible to deploy an bdc-model using code (i.e. create the xml "on the fly" then deploy that using code)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sure it is. Visual Studio 2010 has even a project item template for it. Have a look here http://troyscott.ca/2010/08/07/bdc-models-in-visual-studio-2010-for-sharepoint-foundation-server-2010/ for something to get you started.

The ECT gets created automatically by your BDC model upon solution deployment.

Comment: but when that is said, it is MUCH easier to get the foundation for the code by using SharePoint Designer :-) (and that is just about the only thing that tool is useful for)

Comment: Thanks for the info, but is is possible to do this "in code"? I.e. not in a Solution/WSP? Or better can I do `var bdcm = this.CreateBdcm(); this.InstallToFarm(bdcm);`?

Comment: what do you mean by "in code" this case, ECMA Javascript? - if your BDC model doesn't exist already on the farm, i don't see it as an easy task. You could create/deploy the model even via SPD (the easy way and no-code solution) and probably with a little effort you could create an instance of the ECT via ECMA script. Otherwise, the best way would be to deploy your model via .WSP

Comment: with "in code" I mean using c# and sharepoint object model.

Comment: You could use this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798311.aspx to create/export your BDC and then use either the UI, or PowerShell (e.g. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/anavijai/how-to-import-bdc-model-to-the-bdc-metadata-store/) or http://www.sharemuch.com/2010/02/02/importing-sharepoint-2010-bcs-application-model. Haven't tried by code but a similar as the Powershell should do it.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness:

I found what I was looking for in the [MSDN-Article "Code Snippet: Create an External Content Type Using the Administration Object Model"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff464321.aspx).